# How to Make my developed app rotation work properly

Tags: java, android, android-layout

When I run the app on a real device and I rotate the app to landscape mode most of the content is been cut off and I can't even scroll on the landscape mode.  What XML or java code can I use to make the app  rotate without loosing it content?

Please check the attached image to understand what I mean

[image: portrait mode]

[image: landscape mode]

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Comment: Use a ScrollView, or redefine your layout within `res/layout-land`

Comment: create layouts for landscape and portrait. Use linearlayout with orientation vertical for portrait and orientation horizontal for landscape. make sure you have proper paddings

Comment: Make the top-level element of your layout a `ScrollView`.

Comment: @shmosel I want to make my android application rotation work normally just like apps like Facebook WhatsApp. When rotated it content is not cut off

Answer (score 2):

In the folder "res":

- create a new folder named "layout-land" where you copy the layout (the layout need to have the same name).
- Modify the content of the layout as you desire to fit the landscape.

When you rotate your phone, the system will detect that it exist a layout land folder and a layout adapted for landscape.

Can you post your layout code? I will help you to organize the views.

Comment: i have been trying to post the code here but i don't know how to post it  because i keep getting word exceed limit